# How to click a button ajax via casperjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, casperjs

This is my code. It run ok, it access site, and fill zipcode ok. But i dont know why it cant click button "GO" . What wrong in my code ? Thank you

Site is: https://www.az.aaa.com/membership/gift-membership-form?promocode=zumz0

Thank you !

```js
var casper = require("casper").create();
var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);

var casper = require('casper').create({
 verbose: true,
   logLevel: 'debug',     // debug, info, warning, error
 clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"],
 pageSettings:{
  loadImages: true,
  loadPlugins: false,
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
 }
}
 
);

var fs = require('fs');

//var password = casper.cli.get(1);

function strip_tags(str) {
    str = str.toString();
    return str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
}

casper.start().thenOpen("https://www.az.aaa.com/membership/gift-membership-form?promocode=zumz0", function(){
 console.log("1. Access Site");
});

casper.waitForSelector('#edit-zipcode', function(){
 console.log("2. Box Zipcode Found ! ");
 this.capture('site_box_zipcode.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
 fs.write("debug_zipcode.html", this.getPageContent(), 'w');
});


casper.then(function(){
 console.log("3. Filling Form Zipcode")
 this.evaluate(function(){
  $('#edit-zipcode').attr('value', '86322');
  $('#edit-tqs1-submit').click();
  //document.getElementById("edit-zipcode").value='86322';
  //document.getElementById("edit-tqs1-submit").click();
 });
 
 //this.mouse.rightclick('button.col-xs-12 col-md-1 product-button js-product-button pull-right');
})
//


casper.then(function(){
 
 this.wait(7000);//Wait a bit so page loads (there are a lot of ajax calls and that is why we are waiting 6 seconds)
    this.capture('Afterpostzipcode.png');
    console.log("4. Finish Capture Picture");
}); 



casper.then(function(){
 fs.write("debug_fl.html", this.get, 'w');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Have you tried `casper.click('#edit-tqs1-submit')`?